# ZeroTier One Mac change IP

Tags: zerotier

I need your help.

I have had to install the ZeroTier One client to be all together in one serv. But also the idea is to change our IP from ZeroTier to work more comfortably from home. From Windows it is quite easy because you go to system resources and modify it on the network. But in MacOs I have spent several days looking for how to change the private IP only of the ZeroTier. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

A ZeroTier IP address is `virtual` and is thus assigned from the network controller. In order to change this you need to log into your account at https://my.zerotier.com/, go to the `Network` tab and navigate to the network in question and edit the assigned addresses. Once edited the changes will propagate to the nodes on the network automatically.

In practice if you are not experienced with this sort of concept it is best to choose a managed routing scheme that works best for your scenario and let ZeroTier automatically assign addresses for you.